# "Microsoft Blend"-like continuous Drag

Tags: wpf, drag, blend

Microsoft Blend allows changing numeric values of properties like Left, Top etc. through continuous drag. User clicks in the property value box, keeps the button down and drags left or right to decrease/increase the value. Simple.

The special thing about it is that if cursor reaches the left or right end of the screen and user still wants to drag more, they can continue dragging and the cursor will start over from the other end of the screen.

I'm trying to do this in one of my WPF applications using `Thumb` control. Using `DragDetla` event, if I find that the `Thumb` has reach the edge of the screen, I set its position to the far end. But this makes the value of `e.HorizontalChange` as big as the width of entire screen. How can I change Thumb's position **during drag** without affecting horizontal change value?

Comment: You might be able to subclass the Thumb control for better control over its behaviour. Note that controls in WPF encapsulate behaviour, so if there are no properties that allow you to change default behaviour in the desired way, you most likely cannot force the issue from event handlers, either.

Comment: @Joey: Thumbs up. Working in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized this in a WPF control by using a textbox and subscribing to events such as:

- [PreviewMouseDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmousedown)
- [MouseUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.mousedown) and
- [MouseMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.mousemove)
- [MouseEnter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.mouseenter)

The drag until you reach screen limits requires a mouse capture or call to [CaptureMouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse?System_Windows_UIElement_CaptureMouse) method available on any `UIElement`. On the other side, you need to release the mouse at some point which requires a call of the [ReleaseMouseCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture) method. The solution could go like this:

Declare an enumeration to model the drag direction

```
internal enum MouseDirections
{
    None,
    LeftRight,
    UpDown
}
```

Declare a class to keep trak of mouse origin (first location) and current location:

```
internal class MouseIncrementor
{
    private MouseDirections _enumMouseDirection = MouseDirections.None;
    private Point _objPoint;

    private readonly Point _initialPoint;

    public MouseIncrementor(Point objPoint, MouseDirections enumMouseDirection)
    {
        _objPoint = objPoint;
        _initialPoint = _objPoint;
        _enumMouseDirection = enumMouseDirection;
    }

    public MouseDirections MouseDirection
    {
        get
        {
            return _enumMouseDirection;
        }

        protected set
        {
            _enumMouseDirection = value;
        }
    }

    public Point InitialPoint
    {
        get
        {
            return _initialPoint;
        }
    }

    public Point Point
    {
        get
        {
            return _objPoint;
        }

        set
        {
            _objPoint = value;
        }
    }

    internal MouseDirections SetMouseDirection(Point pos)
    {
        double deltaX = this.Point.X - pos.X;
        double deltaY = this.Point.Y - pos.Y;

        if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > Math.Abs(deltaY))
            MouseDirection = MouseDirections.LeftRight;
        else
        {
            if (Math.Abs(deltaX) < Math.Abs(deltaY))
                MouseDirection = MouseDirections.UpDown;
        }

        return MouseDirection;
    }
}
```

I have a custom control that contains a `TextBox` named _PART_TextBox:
                TextBox _PART_TextBox;

...and field for the `MouseIncrementor`:
                MouseIncrementor _objMouseIncr;

...these are wired up like this:

```
            _PART_TextBox.MouseEnter += _PART_TextBox_MouseEnter;
            _PART_TextBox.GotKeyboardFocus += _PART_TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus;
            _PART_TextBox.LostKeyboardFocus += _PART_TextBox_LostKeyboardFocus;
            _PART_TextBox.MouseMove += _PART_TextBox_MouseMove;
            _PART_TextBox.MouseUp += _PART_TextBox_MouseUp;
            _PART_TextBox.PreviewMouseDown += _PART_TextBox_PreviewMouseDown;
            _PART_TextBox.LostMouseCapture += _PART_TextBox_LostMouseCapture;
```

and a number of event handlers are required to get this to work:

```
    private void _PART_TextBox_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _objMouseIncr = null;
    }

    private void _PART_TextBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_objMouseIncr != null)
        {
            var mouseUpPosition = GetPositionFromThis(e);
            if (_objMouseIncr.InitialPoint.Equals(mouseUpPosition))
            {
                _PART_TextBox.Focus();
            }
        }

        _PART_TextBox.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        _objMouseIncr = null;
    }

    private void _PART_TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsKeyboardFocusWithin == false)
        {
            _objMouseIncr = new MouseIncrementor(this.GetPositionFromThis(e), MouseDirections.None);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void _PART_TextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // nothing to do here
        if (_objMouseIncr == null)
            return;

        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            return;

        if (CanIncreaseCommand() == false && CanDecreaseCommand() == false)
        {
            // since we can't parse the value, we are out of here, i.e. user put text in our number box
            _objMouseIncr = null;
            return;
        }

        var pos = GetPositionFromThis(e);
        double deltaX = _objMouseIncr.Point.X - pos.X;
        double deltaY = _objMouseIncr.Point.Y - pos.Y;

        if (_objMouseIncr.MouseDirection == MouseDirections.None)
        {
            // this is our first time here, so we need to record if we are tracking x or y movements
            if (_objMouseIncr.SetMouseDirection(pos) != MouseDirections.None)
                _PART_TextBox.CaptureMouse();
        }

        if (_objMouseIncr.MouseDirection == MouseDirections.LeftRight)
        {
            if (deltaX > 0)
                OnDecrement(LargeStepSize);
            else
            {
                if (deltaX < 0)
                    OnIncrement(LargeStepSize);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (_objMouseIncr.MouseDirection == MouseDirections.UpDown)
            {
                if (deltaY > 0)
                {
                    if (CanIncreaseCommand() == true)
                        OnIncrease();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (deltaY < 0)
                    {
                        if (CanDecreaseCommand() == true)
                            OnDecrease();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        _objMouseIncr.Point = GetPositionFromThis(e);
    }

    private Point GetPositionFromThis(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        return this.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
    }

    private void _PART_TextBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _objMouseIncr = null;
        (sender as TextBox).Cursor = Cursors.ScrollAll;
    }

    private void _PART_TextBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseDragEnabled == false)
            return;

        if (IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
            (sender as TextBox).Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
        else
            (sender as TextBox).Cursor = Cursors.ScrollAll;
    }

    private void _PART_TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _objMouseIncr = null;
        (sender as TextBox).Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
    }
```

The full project is located here: https://github.com/Dirkster99/NumericUpDownLib
Please let me know if I am missing something or if there are additional questions.